# Why does mysql recognise a atribute as a column name

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea

```
void create() {
    Student testStudent = new Student("Andrei","Pop",4,55,null);
    StudentRepo testrepo = new StudentRepo();
    testrepo.create(testStudent);
    assert(testrepo.getAll().size()==4);
    assert(testrepo.getAll().get(3).getTotalCredits()==55);
    testrepo.delete(testStudent);
}
```

Here is the implementation for the method create

```
Statement statement = null;
//getting all the values from Student
String Query = "insert into Student (FirstName,LastName,StudentId,Credits) Values ("+obj.getFirstname() + ","+obj.getLastname()+","+obj.getStudentId()+","+obj.getTotalCredits()+");";
statement=con.createStatement();
int rowcount=statement.executeUpdate(Query);
```

I get the error invalid column name 'Andrei' in field List

Comment: String literals needs to be enclosed with `'` chars. Without it the literal is distinguished as object name.

Comment: can you please write an example?

Comment: `.. Values ('"+obj.getFirstname() + "', '" + obj.getLastname()+"', " + obj.getStudentId() + "," + obj.getTotalCredits() + ");"` I assume that StudentId and Credits are numeric and hence does not need in enclosing.

Comment: Except that you really shouldn't do that - you should use parameterized SQL instead. Search for "SQL injection attack" for just *one* of the many reasons not to embed values in SQL like this.

Comment: oh thanks you're a life saver

Comment: a hello (or warning)  from [Little Bobby Tables](https://bobby-tables.com)